# GroupBy clarification

Tags: linq-to-objects

```
    var listOfDuplicates = gridDatatable.AsEnumerable().
        GroupBy(item => item.Field<int>(Fields.GLAccountKey.Name),item => item.Field<string>(Fields.GLAccountNumber.Name))
            .Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

if I want to add one more grouping in GroupBy() Like above I need item => again. 
Why cannot "reuse" item like in First()?
Also, it seems that when I am using the second grouping the elements for each group will show ONLY these 2 fields comparing with using the only one grouping when I can see in the elements all the fields from the table.
Just want to better understand GroupBy(). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var listOfDuplicates = gridDatatable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(a => new{
                      KeyName = a.Field<int>(Fields.GLAccountKey.Name)
                      , NumberName = a.Field<string>(Fields.GLAccountNumber.Name)
                     }
           )
    .Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grouping => grouping.Select(a => a))
    .ToList();
```

You can group on as many fields as you'd like by using an `anonymous type`. And calling `Select` on the groups gives you access to its items and all their fields. Above, by simply returning `a`, the query will return all fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myListOfDuplicates = gridDatatable.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(item => new{Field = item.Field<int>(Fields.GLAccountKey.Name), S = item.Field<string>(Fields.GLAccountNumber.Name)})
.Where(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1)
.Select(grouping => grouping.Select(a => a))
.ToList();
```

Need to add explicit name to avoid "anonymous type projection should be sample name or member access expression". Can you do it without explicit name?

Comment: Sorry. You do need to provide names for properties of anonymous types that are the product of a method. In this case, the method being `Field<t>()`. That was an oversight in my answer. I'll update it.